# Apache Error during SSL Handshake with remote server

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, ssl, amazon-ec2, proxy

I have apache listening on 443, and web app nodejs listening on 6969 on EC2 linux server.

I have ssl.conf file

```
 <VirtualHost _default_:443>
    SSLEngine On
    SSLProxyEngine On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    SSLProxyVerify none
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off

    ServerAdmin ***@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/***
    ServerName ***
    SSLCertificateFile "***/certificate.crt"
    SSLCertificateChainFile "***/ca_bundle.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "***/private.key"


    ProxyPass /  https://127.0.0.1:6969/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://127.0.0.1:6969/


      <Directory "/var/www/html/***">
         Order deny,allow
         Allow from all
         AllowOverride All
         Require all granted
      </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
```

and file httpd/error_log

```
[Sun Jul 12 18:56:27.176297 2020] [proxy:error] [pid 32374:tid 140253401167616] (20014)Internal error (specific information not available): [client 117.6.62.***:32539] AH01084: pass request body failed to 127.0.0.1:6969 (127.0.0.1)
[Sun Jul 12 18:56:27.176334 2020] [proxy:error] [pid 32374:tid 140253401167616] [client 117.6.62.***:32539] AH00898: Error during SSL Handshake with remote server returned by /
[Sun Jul 12 18:56:27.176339 2020] [proxy_http:error] [pid 32374:tid 140253401167616] [client 117.6.62.***:32539] AH01097: pass request body failed to 127.0.0.1:6969 (127.0.0.1) from 117.6.62.*** ()
[Sun Jul 12 18:56:34.161784 2020] [proxy:error] [pid 32374:tid 140253401167616] (20014)Internal error (specific information not available): [client 117.6.62.***:32542] AH01084: pass request body failed to 127.0.0.1:6969 (127.0.0.1)
[Sun Jul 12 18:56:34.161831 2020] [proxy:error] [pid 32374:tid 140253401167616] [client 117.6.62.***:32542] AH00898: Error during SSL Handshake with remote server returned by /
[Sun Jul 12 18:56:34.161836 2020] [proxy_http:error] [pid 32374:tid 140253401167616] [client 117.6.62.***:32542] AH01097: pass request body failed to 127.0.0.1:6969 (127.0.0.1) from 117.6.62.*** ()
[Sun Jul 12 18:56:47.451390 2020] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 32156:tid 140253690120384] AH00492: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Sun Jul 12 18:56:48.524967 2020] [suexec:notice] [pid 32494:tid 140512587598016] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Sun Jul 12 18:56:48.549325 2020] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 32494:tid 140512587598016] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Sun Jul 12 18:56:48.552155 2020] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 32494:tid 140512587598016] AH00489: Apache/2.4.43 () OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jul 12 18:56:48.552179 2020] [core:notice] [pid 32494:tid 140512587598016] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
```

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is your NodeJS app serving traffic via HTTPS or is it just plain HTTP? By default it would be HTTP. You can verify this by trying to connect via `curl https://localhost:6969`

Comment: @ChrisWilliams thank you so much, I solved this problem by replace https to http in virtualhost ssl conf.

Comment: Added answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was as the result of trying to communicate using HTTPS to the internal node application.

The application was running on HTTPS, updating to HTTP internally resolved this.